# Migrate Cordova into Crosswalk

Tags: android, cordova, migration, crosswalk-runtime

I have a working cordova app which I want to use Crosswalk. Following the migration instructions on https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova/develop_an_application.html I run into the following error when I try to build the app with `$ cordova build android`

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\tools\ant\build.xm
l:720: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\tools\ant\build.xm
l:734: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 4 seconds

C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Kopfrechnen - Kopie\platforms\android\cordova\node_module
s\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,ant,debug,-f,C:\Users\Admin\Deskt
op\Kopfrechnen - Kopie\platforms\android\build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.abs
olute.dir=ant-gen
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\co
rdova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

I have no idea what the problem is, I followed the instructions step by step. Can anyone help me? :-/

Comment: could you try to get rid of spaces in your project path?

Comment: That's no problem - error stays though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use easily crosswalk. You need ionic with the command line :

> ionic browser add crosswalk